# Sending file from URL in REST request Python

Tags: python, rest

This is what I'm currently using to send images to the API:

```
import requests
response = requests.post("http://someAPI",
auth=(username, password),
files={'imgFile': open(filepath, 'rb')}
)
```

It works for local files, but I would like to be able to send images from a URL as well. I know how to do this by saving the file, then opening it as a local file, sending it to the API and then removing it.

Is there any way of doing this without having to save and remove the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringIO`. StringIO is file compatible object which has open,seek,read,write. So you can load data to it and serve from that, without writing file to disk. I normally use this approch for creating CAPTCH.

```
import StringIO
import requests

# Imagine you read the image file in image as base64 encoded...
buff = StringIO.StringIO()
buff.write(image.decode('base64'))
buff.seek(0)
response = requests.post("http://someAPI",
auth=(username, password),
      files={'imgFile': buff}
     )
```